# error: cannot find symbol class Sum in java

Tags: java, android

I have a simple project. In this project I created a java library as follows:

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.Integer;

public class Sum {
    public static Integer counter(int number_1, int number_2){
        return number_1 + number_2;
    }
}
```

And in `MainActivity` class I have the following code:

```
package com.example.tec.myapplication;

import com.example.Sum;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    int number_1 = 100;
    int number_2 = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Integer integer =  Sum.counter(number_1, number_2);
        textView.setText(integer.toString());
    }
}
```

In appearance, My codes have no grammatical problem and I do not get even a warning from the android studio. But when I click on the `run` option I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\tec\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\tec\myapplication\MainActivity.java

    Error:(2, 19) error: cannot find symbol class MyClass
    Error:(17, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable MyClass
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Because the `java` is very like to the `android`, I asked this question here. I think that my problem is grammatical.

Comment: Probably your latest code is not compiled? Do you have the "build automatically" or similar setting enabled?

Comment: "cannot find symbol class MyClass" `Sum` or `MyClass`?